# Pentaho parameter with same name in job and transformation

Tags: pentaho

I have the same name parameter in a job and in a transformation inside this job. I use the same in the transformation for debugging.
The problem is when I execute the job, the transformation doesn't use the value of the job but the transformation.

Example:

job

parameter:

- week 10

transformation

parameter:

- week 30

I need the transformation to use the week 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check option "Pass parameter values to sub transformation" in "execute transformation" step in job.
[image]
and -> use step "Get Variables" in the transformation. You can see my example from [Here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/13MH8D9FN9WD6UI0ehlZW-C7w3Vw1PJkV?usp=sharing)
[image]